# Yii2 concate auto increment alphabet in ArrayHelper::map()

Tags: php, yii2

This is my `activeRadioList`

```
<?= Html::activeRadioList($model, 'qa_value', ot\QuestionAnswer::getAnswerOptions($model), [
            'encode' => false, 
            'separator' => '<br/>',
            'itemOptions' => [
                'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'radio-inline']
            ],              
        ]);  ?>
```

And this is my `getAnswerOption()` function to get options value

```
public static function getAnswerOptions($qModel)
{
    $answerData = $qModel->qaQuestionInstance->getTqiQuestionAns()->asArray()->all();
    return \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($answerData, 'qna_id', function ($model) {
        $l = 'a';
        return $l++.'. '.$model['qna_answer'];
    });    
}
```

This is return like this

[image]

but i want get

a. False

b. True

Comment: try `$l = 'a';
return \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($answerData, 'qna_id', function ($model) use($l) {
    
    return $l++.'. '.$model['qna_answer'];
});` in your `getAnswerOptions` function

Comment: this one is not work ...

Comment: what you are getting after this?

Comment: Since $x='a'; is a char type variable (internally a number) you can do echo ++$x and it will output b.

Comment: no, i can do the $x='a'; is a char type variable but $x++ get the next char like 'b'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I get my output to change in `getAnswerOptions()` function

```
public static function getAnswerOptions($qModel)
{
    $answerData = $qModel->qaQuestionInstance->getTqiQuestionAns()->asArray()->all();
    $l = 'a';
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($answerData as $ad)
    {
        $answerData[$i++]['qna_answer'] = ($l++.'. &nbsp;'.$ad['qna_answer']); 
    }
    return \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($answerData, 'qna_id', function ($model) {
        return $model['qna_answer'];
    });    
}
```